# Combobox that list items based in the selected item in another combobox

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I do have a routine that uses PHP, MySQL and JavaScript. There are two tables: tbl_category and tbl_subcategory just like this:

### tbl_category

1. cat_id
2. cat_name

### tbl_subcategory

1. scat_id
2. cat_parent_id
3. cat_name

They have some information inside like

### tbl_category:

1. Pants
2. Shoes
3. t-Shirts

### tbl_subcategory:

1. 1 Jeans
2. 1 Heavy Duty
3. 2 Boots
4. 2 Sandals
5. 3 Long Sleeves
6. 3 Short Sleeves
7. 3 Polo

I put in the file head the link to the javascript library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

of course I download previously from the jquery website(newer version).

I have now the script routine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("select[name=cat_id").change(function(){
        $("select[name=scat_id]").html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
        $.post("ajax_subcategory.php",
              {cat_id:$(this).val()},
              function(valor){
                 $("select[name=scat_id]").html(valor);
              }
              )
     })
  })
```

Now I have the form, with the select field Category pre-loaded with data from the table tbl_category:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
   <td align="right">Category:</td>
   <td><select name="cat_id" >
          <option value="0">Choose category</option>
    <?php
             $sql1 =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_category ORDER by cat_name")or die(mysql_error());
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
            {
               echo ("<option value=\"$row[cat_id]\"" . ($sql1 == $row["cat_name"] ? " selected" : "") . ">$row[cat_name]</option>");  
            }
          ?></select> 
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td align="right">Sub-category:</td>
   <td><select name="scat_id" selected="selected" >
       <option value="0">Waiting category...</option>
       </select> 
   </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

and then the php file called ajax_subcategory:

```
<?php

include "../connect_to_mysql.php";

$cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];

$sql1 =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_subcategory WHERE cat_parent_id='$cat_id' ORDER by cat_name")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
 {
    echo ("<option value=\"$row[scat_id]\"" . ($sql1 == $row["scat_name"] ? " selected" : "") . ">$row[scat_name]</option>");  
 }
 ?>
```

Done! Everything looks perfect and beautiful. When I select the item in the first combo I can see the Javascript in action and the Loading... showing up but the  the second ComboBox always is empty
don't matter what item I select it shows up empty and become smaller(width).

This is a good routine and I saw working in the web from another website.

Can you guys help me out to find a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Please stop referring select-list or dropdown, as combobox. Its not a combo in any sense. Further, refer to the BalusC's edit to the original question, here stackoverflow.com/posts/4496605/revisions

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to follow step by step troubleshooting to analyze the data. This is what I would do, in your case:

1. Examine the cat_id before posting:

   ```
   $("select[name=cat_id").change(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
   ```
2. Print the string inside your mysql_query (ajax_subcategory page) as it is, and examine if the query is valid. Try this query directly in MySQL console or phpMyAdmin and examine its output.
3. Analyze the ajax response: Use FireBug or the Network tab in Chrome and check the Ajax response. Sometimes, there will be some PHP warnings or notices generated by your ajax_subcategory page.

Note: I do not understand why you check the condition $sql1 == $row["cat_name"]. $sql1 will be a resource Id, and according to your query, $row['cat_name'] is a string representing your sub category name.

As an aside, mysql_* functions are deprecated and their use strongly discouraged. Use mysqli_* functions or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `$row["scat_name"]`  to   `$row["cat_name"]`

```
<?php

    include "../connect_to_mysql.php";

    $cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];

    $sql1 =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_subcategory WHERE cat_parent_id='$cat_id' ORDER by cat_name")or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
     {
        echo ("<option value=\"$row[scat_id]\"" . ($sql1 == $row["cat_name"] ? " selected" : "") . ">$row[cat_name]</option>");  
     }
     ?>
```